# RESTful habtm relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, has-and-belongs-to-many

So let's say I have two `:has_and_belongs_to_many` models that are joined by a simple index table. This is what my routes.rb looks like:

```
match "foo/:id" => "foos#create", :via => :post
match "foo/:id" => "foos#update", :via => :put
match "foo/:id" => "foos#read", :via => :get
match "foo/:id" => "foos#delete", :via => :delete

match "foos/:id/bars" => "foos#add_bar", :via => :post
```

And the last route (the one in question) maps to a the `add_bar` method in the foo_controller.rb which expects a JSON representation of a bar:

```
def add_bar
  @bar = Bar.find(params[:bar][:id])
  if @bar.nil?
    @bar = Bar.create(params[:bar])
    validation_error(@bar.errors) unless @bar.valid?
    @bar.save!
  end
  @foo.bars << @bar
  @foo.save!
  respond(ResponseCode::OK, @bar)
end
```

Does this make sense? I'm matching the behavior of pushing to the collections in rails, but it feels dirty to me from a RESTful standpoint. Maybe I'm wrong. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scratch all of that and use:

```
resources :foos do
  member do
    post 'bars', :to => "foos#add_bar", :as => :add_bar_to
  end
end
```

This gives you the six basic RESTful CRUD routes, plus an `add_bar_to_foo` helper method. Your foos controller should have a `show` method instead of `read`. This is Rails convention.

To handle adding bars,

```
def add_bar
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id]) # find the foo
  @bar = @foo.bars.build(params[:bar]) # build new bar through foo
  if @bar.save
    render :json => @bar # 'OK' response
  else
    render :json => @bar, :status => :unprocessable_entity # failure response
  end
end
```